# why is the denominator of the correlation coefficient the SD not mean?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

I know dividing SD is to normalise coefficient and take out magnitude factor.
But why not using mean X times mean Y instead of SD of X times SD of Y?

Comment: Lots of reasons, including that one or both of the means may be zero or very close to it (positive or negative).  Means are more of a location parameter while standard deviations more of a scale parameter

Comment: The only useful thing that could achieve is to remove units of measurement. Otherwise consider that if either mean were zero the correlation would be indeterminate, which is absurd: a correlation doesn't stop being defined in that case. Further, even the sign of the correlation would not be guaranteed right (consider negative covariance, one mean negative, the other positive). A positive reason for the definition used is that the magnitude of the covariance can't exceed the product of the standard deviations, so we get results in $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: Many of us understand correlation to be a property of the *standardized variables*: that is, you first change the units of measurement so that the means of $X$ and $Y$ are zero and then you compute something from the results.  Exactly what quantity, then, do you propose to divide by these zeros?